# Too many input arguments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, input, arguments

When I run the following code:

```
xdata2 = [1 3 4 5];
ydata2 = [3 9 76 73];
params = [0.1 0.5 0.0 -0.5 0.2 0.8];
y = svenssontest2(xdata2,ydata2,params,0.636,1.9632);
```

I get the error message "Too many input arguments", but the number of input arguments is correct. Here's the code for the function `svenssontest2`:

```
function [alpha L1 L2] = svenssontest2(tau,Y,params,L1,L2)

tau=tau.';
Y=Y.';

nObs=length(Y);

%z=1;

%for(j =1:50)

    %L2=j/200+0.01;

    %for(k=1:50)

     %   L1=k/200+0.01;

        Lev1= [params(1)*ones(nObs,1) params(2)*(1-exp(-params(5).*tau))./(params(5).*tau) params(3)*((1-exp(-params(5).*tau))./(params(5).*tau)-exp(-params(5).*tau)) params(4)*((1-exp(-params(6).*tau))./(params(6).*tau)-exp(-params(6).*tau))];

        Y=Y-Lev1;

        G= [ones(nObs,1) (1-exp(-L1.*tau))./(L1.*tau) (1-exp(-L1.*tau))./(L1.*tau)-exp(-L1.*tau) (1-exp(-L2.*tau))./(L2.*tau)-exp(-L2.*tau)];

        alpha =G\Y;
        u=Y-G*alpha
        stderr=sqrt(diag((u'*u)/(length(Y)-4)*pinv(G'*G)));
        Sum_u2 = sum(u.^2);
        Res(1,:) = [Sum_u2 alpha' L1 L2];
    %   z=z+1;

   % end
```

Comment: Please edit to place xdata2, ydata, etc as code right before the function call for ease of reproduction. Also Function deceleration needs to be put in the code. 



Once this was done locally, I got this error: 



??? Error using ==> minus Matrix dimensions must agree. Error in ==> svensontest2 at 20 Y=Y-Lev1; 



This has nothing to do with the error message claimed in the question, and in fact implies that the claimed error message is not occurring since we make it into the function.



Please check reproduction steps.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have another file, with the same name and different number of arguments, somewhere in your Path settings, before the Path of this file. Because files are searched top down, the other file is found first, causing this error.

Comment: I had a file named pdist2.m in my Current Folder and as stated by George it somehow gave error when I wanted to call matlab's knnsearch method. I simply deleted this file from the current folder because of I don't need that anymore. Then everything was solved for me.